# How to Make TR and TD Elements Go Across the Whole Page?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to make my navbar, and my table down the bottom of the page be flush with the edges of the page, so that there is no gap above, below left and right between the content and the edges if that makes any sense?

The page is in the beginning stages so the code is a little messy in places, so sorry in advance.

HTML:

```
<html><html
<head>
 <title> Blog | GameHub</title>

 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="Pictures/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new.css">
```

```
 <table class="table" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td class="blog_tops" valign="middle">
    <span>
     <div id="blog_tools">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">New Post</a></li>
       <li><a href="">UserName</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" div id="header"><a href="#"><image div id="logo" border="0" al="lt" height="30px" width="200 src=Pictures/trans_logo.png"></a>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" class="tops" valign="middle">
  <span>
   <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
     <li><a href="forum/overview.php">Forums</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul> 
   </div>
  </span>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="blog_post_title"><div style="float:left;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">UserName</div><div style="float:right;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;">Date</div></td></tr>'    
 <td class="blog_post_content"><p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
 </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
 <td class="blog_post_title"><div style="float:left;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">UserName</div><div style="float:right;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;">Date</div></td></tr>'    
 <td class="blog_post_content"><p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
 </td>
</tr>    
 <tr>
 <td class="blog_post_title"><div style="float:left;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;">UserName</div><div style="float:right;font-size:12px;font-family:verdana;padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;">Date</div></td></tr>'    
 <td class="blog_post_content"><p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 </td>

</tr>
<table class="footer">
 <tr> 
  <td class="copyright">
   <h4></h4>


 </td>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
   #page {
width: 2000px
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #333;
padding: 0px; }


  #navbar ul {
background: #333;
float: none;
padding: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
text-align: left; 
list-style: none; 
width: 100%;
height: 0px; 
vertical-align: top;
min-width: 1046px; }


  #navbar ul li {
display: inline; 
list-style: none; 
vertical-align: top; }


 #navbar ul li a {
background: #333;
color: white;
padding: 5px 0px 5px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-color: #ff6000; 
border-style: solid; 
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: middle;
float: center;  }




 #navbar ul li a:hover {
background: #333;
webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;   
color: #ff6000;}

   #blog_tools ul {
background: #232323;
float: none;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align: right;
list-style: none;
width 100%;
height: 25px;
vertical-align: top; }

  #blog_tools ul li {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
vertical-align: top; }

  #blog_tools ul li a {
background: #232323;
color: #fff;
text-align: right;
padding: 0px 5px 0px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
display; inlne;
border-width: 0px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: middle;
float: center; }

   #blog_tools ul li a:hover {
background: #232323;
webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
color: #01c3f3; }

 .table {
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #fff;
width: 100%; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
text-align: center;
border-spacing: 0px;
cellspacing: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;} 

    #header {
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
background: #333333;
border: 0px;
border-spacing: 0px; }


 #logo {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px; }

.tops {
height: 50px;
width: 100%; 
border-spacing: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
vertical-align: center;
border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ff6000; }


.blog_tops {
height: 0px;
width: 100%; 
border-spacing: 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
vertical-align: center;
border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ff6000; }


h1 {
text-decoration: underline;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 20px; 
padding: 0px;
text-align: top; }

h2 {
font-family: verdana; }

h3 {
font-family: verdana; }

p {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 11pt;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px; }

 a {
font-family: verdana; }


td {
border-width: 0px;
border-style: dotted; 
border-color: olive; 
padding: 0px; }

tr {
padding: 0px;}

.copyright {
height: 200px;
width: 500px;
background-color: #3a3a3a;
padding: 0px 100px 0px 100px; 
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,2); }

.copyright h4 {
color: #fff; }

.footer {
width: 100%;
margin: 20px auto;
background: #232323;
padding: 10px 400px 10px 400px; }
```

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: If you put your example in jsfiddle.net its a lot easier for others to help you

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You only a `table` once but close it three times. Also your first `tr` only has 1 `td` and your others have 2.

Comment: I open 2 tables and I have now changed it so I close 2, but that doesn't help me, and I didn't understand the last part of your comment.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do?I can't figure out what it is that you want to do with your page!

Comment: Make it so that the navbar that has the links "New Post" and "UserName" and the darker box down the bottom touch the edges of the page.

Comment: dont use table for design, use divs. divs are meant to be used for layout.

Comment: Ok Ryan,I am sorry that I am acting silly,But I still can't understand what you want to do.Can you make a picture or something of what you have in mind?

Comment: http://gamehub.clanteam.com/emple.png

Comment: Ryan,I know I am asking too much questions,But I am really trying to help!Your html has about 30 errors,your ending tags are wrong or confusing!I pasted your codes in visual studio and the layout is not at all like what you described!Can you make the corrections?

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use tables for layout!**

The table element is for tabular data, and nothing else. And when you actually start writing HTML then use HTML5 and the semantically correct elements.

So instead of `<div id="navbar">` you use `<nav>`.

Also do not use inline-styles.

There are thousands of tutorials out there, how to write semantically correct HTML(5) and about the [**Separation of presentation and content**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content).

And to assume a viewport width of 2000px (`#page {width: 2000px;}`) is also not up to date, where more and more users use mobile devices with small(er) displays (viewports).

Last but not least are there several typos in your code. So for example you've forgotten a lot of quotes like here `width="200 src=Pictures/trans_logo.png">`. To [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your code is always a good idea.